# Creating URL via JavaScript on image click

Tags: javascript, image, sas

I am trying to call a Javascript function when an image is clicked and then send the user to a new page with appended URL values.

I have a JavaScript Function that saves the value of a hidden textbox.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    function saveMultiSelection() {
    document.getElementById
    ('degStudLevComma').value = $("#degStudLev").
    multipleSelect('getSelects');
};
</script>
```

When I call the function via a standard input button the JavaScript works great.  When I try to call the function via an image the JavaScript is not called.

```
<a href=testurl&_action=execute
%nrstr(&degStudLev=)&degStudLev
target=_blank onclick='saveMultiSelection()'><img 
src='testimage.png'/></a>
```

Comment: That JavaScript should not be working at all. Mainly because the double double quotes `$(""..."")` need to be `$("...")`. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: The extra quotes were left over from pasting my code out of SAS.  I simplified the code a bit and removed as much SAS as possible.  Note the %nrstr() is a SAS function .

Comment: Most likely the click event is being processed by the &lt;a&gt; element, and not the image.

Reorganize your DOM, and try again.

Comment: Dave, I’m not sure what you mean by reorganize my DOM.

Comment: …The JavaScript function is actually being called.  I’m running into a different unexpected problem.

Comment: I’m having a hard time determining which comes first the onclick or the URL. ...nm all documentation states onclick happens first.

Comment: If you are creating the image from within sas you may want to look into using the imagemap option.

Answer (score 0):

If you bind a click event listener to your image like this:

```
<img id="foo" src='testimage.png'/>

  document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
     //here you can do anything you like 
     saveMultiSelection();
     window.location = 'http://www.something.com';
  });
```

does it works?